# Paradigm for scheduled push notification server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, server, push-notification

I'm implementing a full backend for a mobile app, and while I am competent implementing mobile apps and simple mode servers, I have never set up the infrastructure for servers, db, etc.

Basically, I require a simple RESTful api server for communication with my app using Node.js, but my app will have schedules notifications throughout the day that the user can set.

Is it better to have just one server (can scale up as needed but no we will not have many users to start) that takes in the api requests and schedules push notifications with a scheduler library of some sort (making sure of course to not block the execution thread too much when this happens), or is it better to have a lambda function that makes another call to another server dedicated towards sending these notifications?

Or is there another standard to doing something similar to this? Im just not sure what the standard is here. I plan on using AWS services fyi.

I couldn't find much help on the web, so any suggestions are extremely helpful and appreciated!

Thanks in advance!